# Преобразования простых предложений в придаточные

Tags: синтаксис, лексика, стилистика

Вопрос из задания

Преобразуйте выделенные фрагменты предложений в придаточные части времени, условия, причины или следствия. При необходимости измените последовательность частей предложений.

**1. Уничтожение земель и экосистем происходит в результате их разрушения водой при формировании береговой линии.**

Я написала:

**Уничтожение земель и свойственных им экосистем происходит из за того, что они разрушаются водой при формировании береговой линии.**

Но предложение звучит как-то шероховато. Может, есть еще варианты? Или кто-нибудь исправит мой вариант?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш вариант верен, только **из-за** пишется через дефис. И ещё совет - лучше лишних слов в текст не вносить,т.к. меняется смысл.

Возможны другие варианты:

Уничтожение земель и экосистем происходит **оттого**, что их разрушает вода при формировании береговой линии.

Уничтожение земель и экосистем происходит, **когда** их разрушает вода при формировании береговой линии.

Уничтожение земель и экосистем происходит, **если** их разрушает вода при формировании береговой линии.

Comment: Спасибо! В действительности, в оригинале (откуда взято предложение, был именно такой вариант: и свойственных им экосистем.. А в задании эту часть убрали. Я даже и не заметила. Скопировала предложение из интернета(т. к задание было на скриншоте) и исправила этот вариант, даже не заметив разницы.